# Google Fonts without specified subset in stylesheet

Tags: css, google-fonts, unicode-range

Today I ran into a Google Font that's not loaded the usual way, and I'm hoping that someone can clarify this for me.

Why do some Google Fonts not have specified subsets in the stylesheets?

Here's an example of Roboto:

```
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0301, U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7mxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4WxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7WxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

And here's an example of Train One:

Full stylesheet can be found here: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Train+One

```
/* [2] */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Train One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/trainone/v13/gyB-hwkiNtc6KnxUVjWHP87JR5-7NdB589yspgpx0N7r5-25NB8.2.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+ffd7, U+ffda-ffdc, U+ffe0-ffe2, U+ffe4, U+ffe6, U+ffe8-ffee, U+1f100-1f10c, U+1f110-1f16c, U+1f170-1f1ac, U+1f200-1f202, U+1f210-1f234;
}
/* [3] */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Train One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/trainone/v13/gyB-hwkiNtc6KnxUVjWHP87JR5-7NdB589yspgpx0N7r5-25NB8.3.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+fa10, U+fa12-fa6d, U+fb00-fb04, U+fe10-fe19, U+fe30-fe42, U+fe44-fe52, U+fe54-fe66, U+fe68-fe6b, U+ff02, U+ff04, U+ff07, U+ff51, U+ff5b, U+ff5d, U+ff5f-ff60, U+ff66, U+ff69, U+ff87, U+ffa1-ffbe, U+ffc2-ffc7, U+ffca-ffcf, U+ffd2-ffd6;
}
/* [5] */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Train One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/trainone/v13/gyB-hwkiNtc6KnxUVjWHP87JR5-7NdB589yspgpx0N7r5-25NB8.5.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+9e8b-9e8c, U+9e8e-9e8f, U+9e91-9e92, U+9e95-9e96, U+9e98, U+9e9b, U+9e9d-9e9e, U+9ea4-9ea5, U+9ea8-9eaa, U+9eac-9eb0, U+9eb3-9eb5, U+9eb8, U+9ebc-9ebf, U+9ec3, U+9ec6, U+9ec8, U+9ecb-9ecd, U+9ecf-9ed1, U+9ed4-9ed5, U+9ed8, U+9edb-9ee0, U+9ee4-9ee5, U+9ee7-9ee8, U+9eec-9ef2, U+9ef4-9ef9, U+9efb-9eff, U+9f02-9f03, U+9f07-9f09, U+9f0e-9f12, U+9f14-9f17, U+9f19-9f1b, U+9f1f-9f22, U+9f26, U+9f2a-9f2c, U+9f2f, U+9f31-9f32, U+9f34, U+9f37, U+9f39-9f3a, U+9f3c-9f3f, U+9f41, U+9f43-9f47, U+9f4a, U+9f4e-9f50, U+9f52-9f58, U+9f5a, U+9f5d-9f61, U+9f63, U+9f66-9f6a, U+9f6c-9f73, U+9f75-9f77, U+9f7a, U+9f7d, U+9f7f, U+9f8f-9f92, U+9f94-9f97, U+9f99, U+9f9c-9fa3, U+9fa5, U+9fb4, U+9fbc-9fc2, U+9fc4, U+9fc6, U+9fcc, U+f900-f92c;
}
/* [6] */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Train One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/trainone/v13/gyB-hwkiNtc6KnxUVjWHP87JR5-7NdB589yspgpx0N7r5-25NB8.6.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+9c3e, U+9c41, U+9c43-9c4a, U+9c4e-9c50, U+9c52-9c54, U+9c56, U+9c58, U+9c5a-9c61, U+9c63, U+9c65, U+9c67-9c6b, U+9c6d-9c6e, U+9c70, U+9c72, U+9c75-9c78, U+9c7a-9c7c, U+9ce6-9ce7, U+9ceb-9cec, U+9cf0, U+9cf2, U+9cf6-9cf7, U+9cf9, U+9d02-9d03, U+9d06-9d09, U+9d0b, U+9d0e, U+9d11-9d12, U+9d15, U+9d17-9d18, U+9d1b-9d1f, U+9d23, U+9d26, U+9d2a-9d2c, U+9d2f-9d30, U+9d32-9d34, U+9d3a, U+9d3c-9d3f, U+9d41-9d48, U+9d4a, U+9d50-9d54, U+9d59, U+9d5d-9d65, U+9d69-9d6c, U+9d6f-9d70, U+9d72-9d73, U+9d76-9d77, U+9d7a-9d7c, U+9d7e, U+9d83-9d84, U+9d86-9d87, U+9d89-9d8a, U+9d8d-9d8e, U+9d92-9d93, U+9d95-9d9a, U+9da1, U+9da4, U+9da9-9dac, U+9dae, U+9db1-9db2, U+9db5, U+9db8-9dbd, U+9dbf-9dc4, U+9dc6-9dc7, U+9dc9-9dca, U+9dcf, U+9dd3-9dd7, U+9dd9-9dda, U+9dde-9de0, U+9de3, U+9de5-9de7, U+9de9, U+9deb, U+9ded-9df0, U+9df3-9df4, U+9df8, U+9dfd-9dfe, U+9e02, U+9e07, U+9e0a, U+9e0d-9e0e, U+9e10-9e12, U+9e15-9e16, U+9e19-9e1f, U+9e75, U+9e79-9e7d, U+9e80-9e85, U+9e87-9e88;
}
/* [7] */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Train One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/trainone/v13/gyB-hwkiNtc6KnxUVjWHP87JR5-7NdB589yspgpx0N7r5-25NB8.7.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+9ae5-9ae7, U+9ae9, U+9aeb-9aec, U+9aee-9aef, U+9af1-9af5, U+9af7, U+9af9-9afb, U+9afd, U+9aff-9b06, U+9b08-9b09, U+9b0b-9b0e, U+9b10, U+9b12, U+9b16, U+9b18-9b1d, U+9b1f-9b20, U+9b22-9b23, U+9b25-9b2f, U+9b32-9b35, U+9b37, U+9b39-9b3b, U+9b3d, U+9b43-9b44, U+9b48, U+9b4b-9b4f, U+9b51, U+9b55-9b58, U+9b5b, U+9b5e, U+9b61, U+9b63, U+9b65-9b66, U+9b68, U+9b6a-9b6f, U+9b72-9b79, U+9b7f-9b80, U+9b83-9b87, U+9b89-9b8b, U+9b8d, U+9b8f-9b94, U+9b96-9b97, U+9b9a, U+9b9d-9ba0, U+9ba6-9ba7, U+9ba9-9baa, U+9bac, U+9bb0-9bb2, U+9bb4, U+9bb7-9bb9, U+9bbb-9bbc, U+9bbe-9bc1, U+9bc6-9bc8, U+9bca, U+9bce-9bd2, U+9bd4, U+9bd7-9bd8, U+9bdd, U+9bdf, U+9be1-9be5, U+9be7, U+9bea-9beb, U+9bee-9bf3, U+9bf5, U+9bf7-9bfa, U+9bfd, U+9bff-9c00, U+9c02, U+9c04, U+9c06, U+9c08-9c0d, U+9c0f-9c16, U+9c18-9c1e, U+9c21-9c2a, U+9c2d-9c32, U+9c35-9c37, U+9c39-9c3a, U+9c3d;
}
/* [8] */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Train One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/trainone/v13/gyB-hwkiNtc6KnxUVjWHP87JR5-7NdB589yspgpx0N7r5-25NB8.8.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+98eb, U+98ed-98ee, U+98f0-98f1, U+98f3, U+98f6, U+9902, U+9907-9909, U+9911-9912, U+9914-9918, U+991a-9922, U+9924, U+9926-9927, U+992b-992c, U+992e, U+9931-9935, U+9939-993e, U+9940-9942, U+9945-9949, U+994b-994e, U+9950-9952, U+9954-9955, U+9958-9959, U+995b-995c, U+995e-9960, U+9963, U+9997-9998, U+999b, U+999d-999f, U+99a3, U+99a5-99a6, U+99a8, U+99ad-99ae, U+99b0-99b2, U+99b5, U+99b9-99ba, U+99bc-99bd, U+99bf, U+99c1, U+99c3, U+99c8-99c9, U+99d1, U+99d3-99d5, U+99d8-99df, U+99e1-99e2, U+99e7, U+99ea-99ee, U+99f0-99f2, U+99f4-99f5, U+99f8-99f9, U+99fb-99fe, U+9a01-9a05, U+9a08, U+9a0a-9a0c, U+9a0f-9a11, U+9a16, U+9a1a, U+9a1e, U+9a20, U+9a22-9a24, U+9a27, U+9a2b, U+9a2d-9a2e, U+9a31, U+9a33, U+9a35-9a38, U+9a3e, U+9a40-9a45, U+9a47, U+9a4a-9a4e, U+9a51-9a52, U+9a54-9a58, U+9a5b, U+9a5d, U+9a5f, U+9a62, U+9a64-9a65, U+9a69-9a6c, U+9aaa, U+9aac-9ab0, U+9ab2, U+9ab4-9ab7, U+9ab9, U+9abb-9ac1, U+9ac3, U+9ac6, U+9ac8, U+9ace-9ad3, U+9ad5-9ad7, U+9adb-9adc, U+9ade-9ae0, U+9ae2-9ae4;
}
/* [9] */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Train One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/trainone/v13/gyB-hwkiNtc6KnxUVjWHP87JR5-7NdB589yspgpx0N7r5-25NB8.9.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+971d, U+9721-9724, U+9728, U+972a, U+9730-9731, U+9733, U+9736, U+9738-9739, U+973b, U+973d-973e, U+9741-9744, U+9746-974a, U+974d-974f, U+9751, U+9755, U+9757-9758, U+975a-975c, U+9760-9761, U+9763-9764, U+9766-9768, U+976a-976b, U+976e, U+9771, U+9773, U+9776-977d, U+977f-9781, U+9785-9786, U+9789, U+978b, U+978f-9790, U+9795-9797, U+9799-979a, U+979c, U+979e-97a0, U+97a2-97a3, U+97a6, U+97a8, U+97ab-97ac, U+97ae, U+97b1-97b6, U+97b8-97ba, U+97bc, U+97be-97bf, U+97c1, U+97c3-97ce, U+97d0-97d1, U+97d4, U+97d7-97d9, U+97db-97de, U+97e0-97e1, U+97e4, U+97e6, U+97ed-97ef, U+97f1-97f2, U+97f4-97f8, U+97fa, U+9804, U+9807, U+980a, U+980c-980f, U+9814, U+9816-9817, U+9819-981a, U+981c, U+981e, U+9820-9821, U+9823-9826, U+982b, U+982e-9830, U+9832-9835, U+9837, U+9839, U+983d-983e, U+9844, U+9846-9847, U+984a-984b, U+984f, U+9851-9853, U+9856-9857, U+9859-985b, U+9862-9863, U+9865-9866, U+986a-986c, U+986f-9871, U+9873-9875, U+98aa-98ab, U+98ad-98ae, U+98b0-98b1, U+98b4, U+98b6-98b8, U+98ba-98bc, U+98bf, U+98c2-98c8, U+98cb-98cc, U+98ce, U+98dc, U+98de, U+98e0-98e1, U+98e3, U+98e5-98e7, U+98e9-98ea;
}

/* The list goes on to [117] ... */
```

Roboto has unicode-ranges with the subset's name commented above each `@font-face` statement, while Train One seems to have ever expanding unicode-ranges with numbers commented above each `@font-face` statement. The list goes on till 117, btw.

The reason why I'm curious, is because it seems to load three font files, just to display Latin characters.

[image: Train One requires three font files to display Latin characters]

Is this just a very inefficiently built stylesheet, or is there a specific reason why the stylesheet is built this way?

BTW. if it isn't clear, this is a question specifically regarding the Google Fonts API and the way it generates stylesheets. I understand what unicode-ranges are used for. I just don't understand what the Google Fonts API is trying to achieve with such a large amount of @font-face statements and unicode-ranges.

Comment: As for your second question, you may want to import specific characters from specific fonts for stylistic reasons. I would not consider it efficient, but that's really a matter of opinion. Se for example this old CodePen: https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/NWrQwq or this article about it: https://www.sitepoint.com/joy-of-subsets-web-fonts/

Comment: I figured since it's CSS generated by an API and I wasn't asking a question to "help me fix code" it didn't matter. However, I see how images can be inconvenient in other scenarios. I've updated the post.

Comment: Seems like the CSS is fixed now If you scroll down see  a [latin subset](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Train+One&display=swap)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @herrstrietzel. However, it doesn't explain what the [1], [2], [3], etc. mean. I started to carefully assume it's a way to support Chinese symbols, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Daan van den Bergh: I'm afraid it's just a quirky subsetting style the designer found useful. I assume the API generates the subset font-faces based on the individual font files. If it can't map the fonts glyph map to a common language range it probably adds a generic numerical "identifier" comment. Fortunately, I never came across another similarly complicated example on google fonts ;)

Comment: Thanks, @herrstrietzel. That's the most sensible answer I've come across since asking this question!